# How to define a typescript type for a dictionary with generic keys?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

While trying to map the keys of data I'm getting several Typescript errors and I don't understand why. I'm getting back as a response from my API an object with generic keys as followed:

```
{
  1: { 
      name: 'test1',
      country: 'test1',
  },
  2: {
       name: 'test2',
      country: 'test2',
  }
  ....generic amount of keys
}
```

I have defined the following typescript type for this:

```
export type Users<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: {
    name: string;
    country: string;
  };
};
```

When I'm trying to map on the keys of this typed object in my component I'm gtting an error from typescript:

```
Object.keys(data).map((key) => {
  <p>{data[key].name}</p>
})
```

Error on Object.keys(data) line:

> const data: Users | undefined No overload matches this call.
> Overload 1 of 2, '(o: {}): string[]', gave the following error.
> Argument of type 'Users | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type '{}'.
> Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type '{}'.   Overload 2 of 2, '(o: object): string[]', gave the following error.
> Argument of type 'Users | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'object'.
> Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'object'.ts(2769) No quick fixes available

Error on data[key].name:

> Object is possibly 'undefined'.

Comment: I'm wondering your keys would be `string` too? like this `"keyHere": { name: 'test2', country: 'test2' }`

Comment: Can you show how do you set data? Because it seems that it can be undefined, and that could be your issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*From the TSConfig reference [`noUncheckedIndexedAccess`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noUncheckedIndexedAccess):*

> TypeScript has a way to describe objects which have unknown keys but known values on an object, via index signatures.
>
> Turning on `noUncheckedIndexedAccess` will add `undefined` to any un-declared field in the type.

You can use the [non-null assertion operator (postfix `!`)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#non-null-assertion-operator-postfix-) to inform the compiler that the value definitely exists. Here's an example:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbwCYFMBmBDArgG3hgZzgCUUMBjGAXzjSghDgHIozKmBuAWACheYAnmBRwAqgRRQ4AXkS84cAHYYQKAFxwCMKMEUBzbjwXkIWRdoEatO-Yaq9eJxVrhIMMDBtImoSADzWunoANGISUAB8MnJGcACMGghw8gpKKurMMChacUzBKcam5lCWmdkwufmxVFUKAEyJBWmqGkxZWnV5TSZmFq3tMJ21cDUpAPRjcAB0M1N6KIqSwORwKkXwEGhwANYoAgS8VIa8APIARgBWKJRTu-sAFG4eAJRTIBhg93cyUfd+YBFkO4MABtO4AXQAhFNlKoqH4xgDns9DBNUuiMZisdjsQA9XhogAqAAsRIoIIoALSKXA4VYEcIwYAUuAQYRQdzQOAAd2AODphEZBMmMAgcBgpLgJnAfMk4uJ7nlIgAbhgcFgRCgAB7ALQHHhAA)

```ts
import {default as React} from 'react';

type User = {
  name: string;
  country: string;
}

const data: Record<string, User> = {
  1: { 
    name: 'test1',
    country: 'test1',
  },
  2: {
    name: 'test2',
    country: 'test2',
  },
  // ....generic amount of keys
};

Object.keys(data).map(key => (<p>{data[key]!.name}</p>));
//                                         ^
// The non-null assertion operator will assert
// to the compiler that the value exists
```